# Access database connection in JSP

Tags: database, jsp, ms-access, connection

i have seen examples in stackoverflow wherein MS access database connection is established for access files stored in the same desktop/system C/D drive.. can a connection be established for MS access file stores in different system.

(Am writing code in JSP in my laptop whereas the required MS access files is in use in another server..sorry i cant copy access file to my system)

Comment: what you using Internet or LAN ?

Comment: using local LAN

Comment: check my answer it will help you .using UNC.If it doesnot work ,then you may need to change DB.

Answer (score 0):

For database In Ms. Access .**mdb** file is responsible

The answer depends on how you are able to connect to the other machine. The Corresponding .mdb file can be accessed using LAN on the same machine .

By accessing **share mapped to drive letter D:**

```
Dbq=D:\yourdbfile.mdb
```

**Or use the UNC path:**

```
Dbq=\\machine_name\share_name\yourdbfile.mdb
```

This is Test Case with windows 7 and windows 8.(For other please mention.)

Comment: Thanks  a lot..will try it

Comment: @noobprogrammer you need to select the answer..as being a new commer your vote wont be counted.